# parent div have text-align:left;

Tags: html, css

A `<div>` element has `text-align:left; width:500px;` and, inside it, a child `<div>` has more than 20 other `<div>` elements with `width:20px;`.

My question is, without using `float:left` how we can put all elements side by side from the left?

---

Screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: You have to justify why you are not using float which is designed for exactly this.

Comment: child divs will expand vitriolically dynamically if i am using float:left it gaps will come...

Comment: no you cannot because div is block element. Hence cannot be float without float property. You can use span which is a inline instead

Comment: but i saw some sites with out having float property divs are floating left...

Comment: vitriolically? Can you show us images of what you have and what you expect?

Comment: i dont have enough reputations to send the image...

Comment: this is the screen shot getting white space when clicking on any buddy icon. if normal it will good. http://tinypic.com/r/15wu29/7

Comment: http://i52.tinypic.com/15wu29.png

Comment: Please show your HTML and CSS, if you can't allow access to your actual site, use jsFiddle.net

Comment: it is big code to take off. can u explain how to avoid that white spance when clicking on it it will expand the div.

Comment: Every buddy will come with float:left; when clicking on any buddy will expand. if clicking on first column no issue. if clicking on any buddy on second second column first column will show the white space. as well as third.

Comment: Hii this is the sample html http://jsfiddle.net/WhDNR/1/

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that `display: inline-block` will get you pretty close to what you want. It will generate a block box for the contents (allowing you to specify block level properties such as `width`), which will then be flowed inline.

Comment: "I would guess" - We're not here for guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS3 Columns Module `column-count` property for this. You will also need to include the `-moz` and `-webkit` version for compatibility reasons:

```
#container {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
```

Unfortunately, this property is not available on all versions of IE, so you'll need a Javascript alternative.

A good method would be to check for `column-count` support with [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), then create two additional container elements each one-third the width of the parent, then using Javascript we can watch for expansions and pull the necessary number of elements to the other two to maintain even sizes.